# Creating an executable file using INNO SETUP Compiler 5.3.8

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

i have a problem when i create an executable file of my application created using `VisualStudio 2010` and `MSAccess 2010`. I instal the application and I create a shortcut but when i run the application an error is generated saying that the Data Base file is not found in the same directory of the shortcut (when i create a shortcut in desktop : BD.accdb  not found in C:\Users\Achraf\Desktop\BD.accdb or when i run the application from Start-> all programs-> MyApp :BD.accdb not found in C:\Windows\System32\BD.accdb) .

Answer (score 0):

Please check the working directory set for the shortcut. This is set in the "`Start In`" property when you view the properties of the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provide the full path to the file using `{app}`:

```
Filename: {app}\BD.accdb; WorkingDir: {app}
```